# directExecutor method missing in guava library

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using google's grpc library in my android app which relies on the google guava library. For some reason the guava embedded in grpc doesn't have 'directExecutor' method in the class `MoreExecutors.` But the method is present in the github version? What accounts for the discrepancy?

In a class called ClientCallImpl is where the call to directExecutor is made. On the import statement(`import static com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor;`) AndroidStudio shows a `can't resolve symbol` message, but the build doesn't fail. The exception is raised when the call is made during execution.

**Error Message**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
    Process: com.asdf.asdf, PID: 4025
             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor; in class Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors' appears in /data/data/com.fentale.dalol/files/instant-run/dex/slice-guava-jdk5-17.0_a8ada10dcaf113cb6e3b4d3e5b46975833f8ae8f-classes.dex)
                at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.<init>(ClientCallImpl.java:100)
                at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:320)
                at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:299)
                at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:130)
                at com.fentale.dalol.nano.DalolGrpc$DalolBlockingStub.topPosts(DalolGrpc.java:365)
```

**EDIT**

It seems the problem is that my project has dependencies on both `guava-18.0` and `guava-jdk5-17.0.` The method I want `directExecutor` is only defined in the MoreExecutors class of guava-18, not 17. But the code is looking for it in the latter version of the class. How can I resolve this.

Comment: Hey @Michael were you able to resolve this ? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @NameisNilay Checkout my answer.

Comment: I do not have Youtube dependency in my app. So this is useless. Apart from that I wrote exclude module: 'guava-jdk5' for every import, but still cannot resolve the error. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

My app had a dependency on the youtube library which inturn depended on guava. However youtube's guava dependency is from a different source than grpc's and using an older version. Two versions of the guava jar existed in the app and grpc was accessing youtube's older guava version rather than its own, which caused the problem.

```
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev164-1.21.0') {
    exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```